# Drain pipe too high for garbage disposal

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

They just installed granite countertops with deep sinks.  Now if I reconnect everything together the drain pipe from the wall is too high.  Short of cutting open the wall and lowering the drain pipe (or doing away with the disposal) is there anything I can do?  I checked and the pipe in the wall goes straight to the left, so there would be extensive destruction to move the wall pipe.

So would either of these work?:

1. Use and elbow and extend the wall pipe to the p-trap?
2. redirect the disposal directly into wall pipe (placing drain after p-trap)?

The distance from the wall pipe center to the top of the p trap is about 4.5”

[image]

Comment: Thanks to these kinds of pictures being added, I have learned that the guts & clutter under the sink look pretty much the same all over the world... this is how we know we live normal lives, and as DIYers we are UNITED under the sink

Answer (score 1):

I couldn’t come up with a good solution, even after talking to an experienced plumber. So I removed the disposal and will relocate it to our utility sink.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its just about right for the U-bend and that will stop smells coming back up.

Comment: If I use an elbow and extend the outside pipe into the ptrap, would that work?  The pipe in the wall goes to the left, not up and down as I had hoped.

Comment: The trap will block gasses from the sewage system, but I think OP is going to have a stinking puddle in that horizontal line and the bottom of his garb. Hard to see, but is that height difference in the pic representative of the real difference or the angle of the pic?

Comment: @P2000 without measurements from a baseline who can say?

Comment: Further to @SolarMike 's  point, I suggest you check that height difference with a level. 1/4in per foot of drop is good. I like using a laser level because it gives me a quick overview and I can have it guide me while I make connections.