# Sink only drains after disposal ran

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

Kitchen sink only drains after I have ran the disposal. I pulled trap apart and it is clear but it was full of water. I saw post regarding similar with issue of outlet being above trap? Is it the set up? Didn't seem to happen with old disposal. [image]

Comment: Or this? [Drain pipe too high for garbage disposal](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/226636/drain-pipe-too-high-for-garbage-disposal)

Comment: Or this? [Can the garbage disposal outlet be lower than the building drain inlet?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/277204/can-the-garbage-disposal-outlet-be-lower-than-the-building-drain-inlet)

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that's a definite problem setup with the drain exit well above the trap weir, and apparently even above the exit from the disposal (which might be a slight bit of the picture making that part look worse than it is.)

It either needs a different disposal, (or no disposal) or a better implementation of the plumbing between the disposal exit and the wall entrance, if the wall is actually below the disposal exit, or a new hole into the pipe in the wall lower down (which is a major but not impossible task - the current hole can be converted to a clean-out.)